# Get id for navigation link

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to add id from JS

```
@Component({
  selector: 'kit-general-16',
  templateUrl: './16.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./16.component.scss'],
})
export class CuiGeneral16Component implements OnChanges {
  @Input() id: string
  @Input() name: string
  @Input() price: string
  @Input() oldPrice: string
  setFavorite() {
    this.isFavorite = !this.isFavorite
  }
  ngOnChanges() {}
}
```

Component:

```
<kit-general-16 [name]="product.name" [price]="product.price" [oldPrice]="product.oldPrice" routerLink="../edit-product/{product.id}"></kit-general-16>
```

How I can replace into `routerLink` the value `{product.id}`?
Currently I get `edit-product/%257Bproduct.id%257D`

Comment: You need 2 curly braces on each side. `{{ product.id }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `routerLink="../edit-product/{product.id}"` to `routerLink="../edit-product/{{product.id}}"`.

So instead of using `{product.id}`, pls use `{{product.id}}`.

[Reference](https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax)